# Disabling touch sliding on listboxes Windows 7

Tags: wpf, touch

Touch sliding support on ScrollViewer is working natively in windows7 (maybe vista). But not in XP.

I want to implement touch sliding in windows XP. To do that, I want to implement a custom sliding that will be working on XP and vista.

How I can disable native sliding support on the the ScrollViewer that I will want to replace to custom sliding?

Answer (score 1):

The PanningMode property of the ScrollViewer will act on native handling of touch events for that control.

In that particular case, to disable listbox panning.

You will have to create a ListBox style and override the ControlTemplate of the listbox to add to the nested ScrollViewer the PanningMode="PanningMode.None" property.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
...
        <ScrollViewer PanningMode="PanningMode.None"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Fixed my problem. Just a note; this property is only available in .NET 4 and above.